# DynamoDB column with tilde and query using JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

i have table column with tilde value like below

```
             vendorAndDate              - Column name

             Chipotle~08-26-2020        - column value
```

I want to query for month "vendorAndPurchaseDate like '%~08%2020'" and for year ends with 2020 "vendorAndPurchaseDate like '%2020'". I am using Spring Data JPA to query the values. I have not worked on column with tilde values before. Please point me in a right direction or some examples

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.
If vendorAndPurchaseDate is your partition key , you need to pass the whole value.
If vendorAndPurchaseDate is range key , you can only perform
= ,>,<>=,<=,between and begins_with operation along with a partition key

reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not support this type of wildcard query.

Let's consider a more DynamoDB way of handling this type of query. It sounds like you want to support 2 access patterns:

1. Get Item by month
2. Get Item by year

You don't describe your Primary Keys (Partition Key/Sort Key), so I'm going to make some assumptions to illustrate one way to address these access patterns.
Your attribute appears to be a composite key, consisting of `<vendor>~<date>`, where the date is expressed by `MM-DD-YYYY`.  I would recommend storing your date fields in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, which would allow you to exploit the sort-ability of the date field.  An example will make this much clearer.  Imagine your table looked like this:

[image]

I'm calling your `vendorAndDate` attribute `SK`, since I'm using it as a Sort Key in this example.  This table structure allows me to implement your two access patterns by executing the following queries (in pseudocode to remain language agnostic):

Access Pattern 1: Fetch all Chipotle records for August 2020

```
  query from MyTable where PK = "Vendors" and SK between Chipotle~2020-08-00 and Chipotle~2020-08-31
```

Access Pattern 2: Fetch all Chipotle records for 2020

```
  query from MyTable where PK = "Vendors" and SK between Chipotle~2020-01-01 and Chipotle~2020-12-31
```

Because dates stored in ISO8601 format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD...) are lexicographically sortable, you can perform range queries in DynamoDB in this way.

Again, I've made some assumptions about your data and access patterns for the purpose of illustrating the technique of using lexicographically sortable timestamps to implement range queries.